# Unknown item label in R

Tags: r, arules

```
rules <- apriori(Day.4,parameter = list(minlen=2, supp=0.005, conf=0.8), appearance = list(rhs=c("Status=D", "Status=G"), default="lhs"), control = list(verbose=F))
rules.sorted <- sort(rules, by="lift")
inspect(rules.sorted)
```

I am trying to run this code, and it shows an error.

> Error in asMethod(object) :    Status=D is an unknown item label,
>   Status=G is an unknown item label.

What seems to be the problem? I am kind of new to R as well.

So any detailed help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that the items `Status=D` and `Status=G` do not exist in your data. Create a transaction set first using

```
 trans <- as(Day.4, "transactions")
 summary(trans)
 itemLabels(trans)
```

Once you have the actual item names then you can use `trans` in the call for `apriori`.